# Open source library to convert images to video other than ffmpeg

Tags: java, android, video, video-processing

I would like to know if there are any open source libraries to convert a set of images to video (not `.MP4`),other than ***ffmpeg***. I need to use this library in my android app hence being compatible for this environment as well.
Any suggestions in this regard will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [JCodec](http://jcodec.org/). It's an open source pure java implementation of video and audio codecs and formats.

Or `Xuggler API` can also be used but since you're looking for something other than `ffmpeg`, this might not be your cup of tea as Xuggler extensively incorporates `FFMPEG` in its functionality.